# Permission required to run Invoke-RestMethod to run Release in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

[image]
I am trying to run a PowerShell script which calls Rest API in Azure DevOps release pipeline. Some users are able to run the release without any errors but for some users they get The remote server returned an error:

> (403) Forbidden. 
>   The authenticated user doesn't have permission to perform the
>   operation.

What kind of permission is required?

Does the user need "Administer process permissions"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (403) Forbidden. The authenticated user doesn't have permission to
>   perform the operation.

**403** is the API response code, as you can see, these users does not have permission to execute the API successfully.

As the **403** defined, it means that sorry, I know who you are, I also know what you want to doing. But unfortunately you do not have permission to do this operation you want to do. So Its permission setting depend on the api you are trying to execute.

As default, if someone does not have enough permission assigned in Org setting/project setting, even though it has the token with **full access**, he or she still could not finish the API successfully what he does not have permission to do.

> what kind of permission is required?
>   Does the user need "Administer process permissions"?

You don't need assign them the administrator role, though this must can solve all permission problem. Just assign the relevant permission to these user according to the actual api.

If you don't mind, you'd better share the api you are using but facing `403 forbidden` error.

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $organizationUri -Body $bodyInfo -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers
I am trying to run a command to create a new Azure DevOps project.

Comment: @wonderfulworldwithcharity I’d better to know the exactly url you want to access-) These command don’t need any permission. The error displayed on this line just because the value of `$organizationUri`

Comment: here you go Merlin "https://dev.azure.com/OrgName/_apis/projects?api-version=5.0"

Comment: @wonderfulworldwithcharity This is the project api and you are trying to run post request. Does the operation you want to do is create a new project?

Comment: Yup, myself is added in the Project Collection Admin group so I am able to run the script without a problem but anyone who is not part of that group gets that 403 error.

Comment: @wonderfulworldwithcharity You can just assign them the permission of **Create new projects**, enter org setting->permission to set it. For PCA member, this is an inherited permission but not for others.

Comment: @wonderfulworldwithcharity You can add these users into one group and set the permission(create new project) of this group to allow. So that you don’t need specify the permission one by one.

Comment: yup I just did that :)

Answer (score 0):

To run a release pipeline the users need **Create Releases** permissions. by default to **Contributes** group has those permissions. so the best is to add them to this group. in addition, you can go to the release security settings and explicitly give to the users those permissions.

[image]

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#release-permissions).